# Provide a flutter app without google or apple store

Tags: flutter, publish

Is it possible to publish a flutter application on a website with an download button and not in google or apple store?

Answer (score 1):

For android yes you can export the app as an apk and host it in your website then let visitors  download it and install it, any android will get a warning  that this app may not be safe to install if user accepts he can proceed  to install  it and it will work, but in the future  if you decided to upload  the app to Google play store, its against  google play terms to do that, they will block your app from play store until you delete the unsigned version from your website.

Comment: Ok, thank you for response and whats about ios?

Comment: About IOS apple doesn't allow that, Im not aware of any legal way to do it you can try learning  about Sideloading Apps for ios, or check Cydia, but Cydia is breaking apple terms i do not recommend it but im letting you know about what others are doing, so i would say for apple you cant install apps without apple store.